# Google Fit on genymotion

Tags: android, google-play, genymotion, google-fit

I am trying to use Google Fit on my Genymotion device for development purposes. I have installed Google Play Services and am able to navigate the Play Store, however, when I go to install Google Fit, I see an error - "Your device isn't compatible with this version".

Here's a screenshot if that helps:
[image]

Device: Google Nexus 6
Android version: 5.1.0
Google Play Services version: 10.2.0

Comment: Have you tried using a real device - android wearable (watch)? If not, please do so.

Comment: Maybe try installing the app from an `apk`: http://www.apkmirror.com/apk/google-inc/fit/

Comment: Thank you @MatanItzhak - that did the trick!